# Auto file-size growth of vmdk

Tags: windows-10, macos, virtualbox

My vbox Mac OS is created using the ~6GB rar file [downloaded from this guide](https://www.wikigain.com/install-macos-high-sierra-virtualbox-windows/). All is good and I see the vmdk file is ~10GB. (The OS folder itself takes up little storage.)

Next, I leave the VM just running "on standby"  and it soon phails with an error popup:

> An error has occurred during virtual machine execution! The error
>   details are shown below. You may try to correct the error and resume
>   the virtual machine execution.
>
> The I/O cache encountered an error while updating data in medium
>   "ahci-0-0" (rc=VERR_DISK_FULL). Make sure there is enough
>   free space on the disk and that the disk is working properly.
>   Operation can be resumed afterwards.
>
> Error ID: BLKCACHE_IOERR Severity: Non-Fatal Error

I see the vmdk file is now 15.5 GB (16,681,336,832 bytes).

What is causing this huge automatic growth in size?

How do I prevent it from growing so much?

---

• The OS folder itself is 470 KB (481,945 bytes), 528 KB (540,672 bytes) on-disk, when thevmdk file is 15.5GB.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: If it goes into standby - I think whatever is in the RAM gets dumped to disk until it is resumed. That is likely your file size increase, depending how much memory you have assigned/it is taking up.